# How do I upgrade Discord to v 0.0.12?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Today I saw that I could update Discord on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS to version 0.0.12. The problem now is that in the Ubuntu Software the newest version is 0.0.11. I also cannot open the .deb file that discord downloads for the update in Ubuntu Software. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall Discord through Ubuntu Software. I also tried to update through the command line with the snap. I used `snap refresh discord` and it said that there were no updates available.

The message I get every time I open Discord:

[image: Discord_message]

Comment: This question should be re-opened. The fundamental problem here is that Discord's internal update mechanism does not complete quickly: you click on the "Download" button shown above, but nothing seems to happen. Download a .deb from the Discord website and installing it from the terminal is one possible solution, but there may well be a *better* solution. E.g. maybe Discord is looking for dpkg in the wrong place - there are many possibilities, but we won't know if the question is closed. The issue is still not fixed with 0.0.13 BTW.

Comment: It seems in the begining you install Discord using .deb file, Even I did same but now this what I did to get rid of this update thing.
----
1) First find discord using `dpkg -l | grep discord`
----
2) Remove previous Discord installed through dpkg using `apt-get --purge remove discord`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you've installed the snap version before, update it with the command `sudo snap refresh discord`

Else if you've installed discord from the official website, update it through the following steps.

1. Go [here](https://discordapp.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb) to download the latest `.deb` file.
2. Open terminal and go to the folder where you've download the file.
3. Install it using `sudo apt install ./<package name>`

Comment: is it advisable to uninstall the previous version first or is it fine just installing the lastest .deb every time?

Comment: You can just install the latest version, using the command I gave you and the package manager will take care of the rest.

Comment: can i also install it in snap? Because now i have two versions, one older snap version and one new apt version. I also need do login again in my discord account.

Comment: When I do this in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the update fails with this message:
`Download is performed unsandboxed as root, as file '/tmp/mozilla_gamer0/discord-0.0.13.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)` . Please see my comment to the question too.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ping @Heisenberg into the comment above.

Comment: There is two discord now thx

Comment: @ch1ll You can uninstall the snap version of discord.

Comment: @fuat you probably had the snap version. Uninstall that and everything will be fine

Comment: @Matthew I'm not sure what about problem is but can you check that if the update was successful by opening discord?

Comment: If you do this, you will have to manually update every time. If you let the snap manager continue managing it, you will get automatic updates. The problem is the snap store is sometimes a little slow to release so there may be a gap between Discord wanting to update and it being available as a snap. That's the tradeoff: manual install/updates for immediate availability, automated updates with slight delay

Comment: @MikeHardy Plus a lot of people don't prefer snaps.

Comment: Of course there are preferences but the stackexchange network is generally for facts and tradeoff exposure. People can then apply their preferences with knowledge, so I didn't get in to that

Comment: @MikeHardy Okay, I've edited the answer now

Comment: @Heisenberg I hope there was no offense taken, I thought it was an okay answer before, I was mostly commenting for people that were stuck the way I was where the snap was not available yet. Then they (me, yesterday) have to either wait or decide to un-snap and go manual. Cheers either way, we're all just trying to help

Comment: @MikeHardy Nah, I don't care much about snaps. I realized that a lot of people must be using snap version so It would be better to add the snap update thingy.

Comment: But also like, snap version is fishy, it has no unicode fonts. Discord packed it awfully or something. And then there is Ubuntu which doesn't update a thing from *.deb, always have to use google and the command line for such trivial stuff!

Comment: Why not use `dpkg` instead?

Comment: ```sudo dpkg -i filename.deb``` worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

Select download on the deb package. Then, wherever you saved this package, do:

```
sudo apt install ./discord-0.0.12.deb
```

Answer (score 4):

Running `sudo snap refresh discord` works as of today. I hope this answered your question.

The response should be something like:

```
Johndoe@pc:~$ sudo snap refresh discord
discord 0.0.12 from Snapcrafters refreshed
Johndoe@pc:~$
```

It may take a bit copying over data.

Comment: I think this might only work if you have the snap version installed.

Comment: @Diatrix, the OP posted about using Ubuntu software center, so I automatically assumed the OP was using snap.

Comment: @puntillol59 Ubuntu 18.04 is still an LTS version that's only half-way through it's life and defaults to .debs in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: There is sometimes a slight delay (some hours, 8 or so?) between release of the manual install .deb packages and availability of the update on the snap store. If you try this `sudo snap refresh discord` command it does not update, that probably means they haven't pushed the snap version of the update out yet. Patience in that case, or uninstall the snap and do a manual install of the .deb release.